# Dataset with Addresses and Building/Structure Type in the US

Tags: data-request, usa, real-estate

I'm looking for a dataset where I can find out an address' building/structure type. I know that the [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/supported_types) will return types but I am looking for a different source which might be more accurate. I've explored contacting city and county assessors and found some datasets with building types but not all cities and counties make the data accessible or free. I'm also hoping there is something more monolithic than contacting each city.

I'm looking for recommendations or for someone to point me in the right direction. Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Any requirements for *building/structure type*? Or is there a common 'standard' in the US?

Answer (score 1):

OSM offers both [address](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Addresses) and [buildings](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Buildings) data.